# Default value for "Insert space after keywords in control flow statements" setting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, ide

Can someone tell me what default value for the "Insert space after keywords in control flow statements" setting is?

I'm not sure if I changed it in the past or whether another developer has it changed it on their end and I would like to suggest we just go with the default so the auto-formatting doesn't cause needless file changes all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no VS 2013 here.  In Visual Studio 2017, the default for "Insert space after keywords in control flow statements" is true.

Comment: Thanks... I'm fairly certain they wouldn't have changed the default so I'll go ahead and mark this the answer :)